# Validate blob image sent by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, security

I have an image cropper that crops the uploaded image, Before sending it to the server using PHP and AJAX.

Here is a [live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmt2pxva/1/) to preview a working cropping example, Upload an image and then crop it by clicking `crop`.

Here is the code:

```js
// Create cropped part.
function getRoundedCanvas(sourceCanvas) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var width = sourceCanvas.width;
  var height = sourceCanvas.height;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  context.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(width / 2, height / 2, Math.min(width, height) / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.fill();
  return canvas;
}

// On uploading a file
$("#input").on("change", function(e) {
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
      file = this.files[0],                   
      image = new Image();
  image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);    
  image.onload = function(e) {
    var image = document.getElementById('image'),
        button = document.getElementById('button');
    $('#image').attr('src',  _URL.createObjectURL(file));
    $('#image').show();
    $('#button').show();
    var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
      aspectRatio: 1,
      movable: false,
      cropBoxResizable: true,
      dragMode: 'move',
      ready: function () {
        croppable = true;
        button.onclick = function () {
          var croppedCanvas;
          var roundedCanvas;
          var roundedImage;
          if (!croppable) {
            return;
          }
          // Crop
          croppedCanvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
          cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
            fillColor: '#fff',
            imageSmoothingEnabled: true,
            imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
          });
          // Round
          roundedCanvas = getRoundedCanvas(croppedCanvas);
          // Show
          roundedImage = document.createElement('img');
          roundedImage.src = roundedCanvas.toDataURL();
          result.innerHTML = '';
          result.appendChild(roundedImage);

        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#image,
#button{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<!-- Cropper CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.4.1/cropper.min.css">
 
 <!-- Cropper JS -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.4.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- File input -->
 <input type="file" id="input" name="image">
 <!-- Selected image will be displayed here -->
 <img id="image" src="" alt="Picture">
 
 <!-- Button to scrop the image -->
 <button type="button" id="button">Crop</button>
 
 <!-- Preview cropped part -->
 <div id="result"></div>
```

Then I use the following code to send a `blob` to PHP using Ajax to save the image on server:

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('avatar', blob);
  // Use `jQuery.ajax` method
  $.ajax('upload.php', {
    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error: function () {
    }
  });
});
```

In `upload.php`:

```
if( isset($_FILES['avatar']) and !$_FILES['avatar']['error'] ){
  file_put_contents( "uploads/image.png", file_get_contents($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']) );
}
```

Should I make some checks for security or just the dimensions and size checks?

Comment: @IncredibleHat, In this case, What should the first parameter(filename) be?

Comment: in this case since you want to allow files to be written securely, create a file location outside server root directory, like = /htdocs/html/ this way the web server does not have direct access to the files.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, In this case all the files will be named "blob"

Comment: @unixmiah, And how to display them to the public then?

Comment: @IncredibleHat, `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".basename($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) . ".png");`

Comment: @IncredibleHat, If I just use the directory name `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/");` , I get errors

Comment: @IncredibleHat, Thanks it's working now with a new file name, But when it comes to displaying the images to the users, Should I then save the original file name or just show the new name?